# Partitioning with IEnumerable source

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I have ConcurrentQueue of type IProducerConsumerCollection i.e.

```
IProducerConsumerCollection<Job> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Job>();
```

and producer method which adds jobs to _queue and consumer method which processes the Job from _queue. Now in the consumer method, I like to process the jobs concurrently. Below is code for sample class with producer and consumer methods:

```
public class TestQueue
{
    IProducerConsumerCollection<Job> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Job>();
    private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public TestQueue()
    {
        WorkProducerThread();
        WorkConsumerThread();
    }

    public void WorkConsumerThread()
    {
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            //At this point, 4 partitions are created but all records are in 1st partition only; 2,3,4 partition are empty
            var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(_queue).GetPartitions(4);

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(
             from partition in partitioner
             select Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 using (partition)
                 {
                     while (partition.MoveNext())
                         await CreateJobs(partition.Current);
                 }
             }));

            t.Wait();

            //At this point, queue count is still 20, how to remove item from _queue collection when processed?
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateJobs(Job job)
    {
        HttpContent bodyContent = null;
        await _client.PostAsync("job", bodyContent);
    }



    public void WorkProducerThread()
    {
        if (_queue.Count == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    Job job = new Job { Id = i, JobName = "j" + i.ToString(), JobCreated = DateTime.Now };
                    _queue.TryAdd(job);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_Log.Error("Exception while adding jobs to collection", ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobCreated { get; set; }
}
```

There are 2 problems,

1. `Partitioner.Create(_queue).GetPartitions(4); Partitioner.GetPartions` creates 4 partitions but all records are in 1st partition only; 2,3,4 partition are empty. I can't find, why this is happening? Ideally, all 4 partitions should have 5 records each (since total 20 records are in queue). I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl) article from MSDN on partitioning but didn't get any clue. Also I checked the partitioning example from [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) article.
2. Also, I want to remove the item from _queue after processing in consumer method and there is only one way _queue.TryTake method to remove item. I don't know how to remove item along with partitioning?

I can consider any alternate way to achieve the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may wish to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue%601.Count);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true re: the risks of using `Count > 0`.

Comment: I used code just after line var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(_queue).GetPartitions(4); and it returns all records in first partition.
foreach (var p in partitioner){
                using (p)
                {
                    while (p.MoveNext())
                        string name = p.Current.JobName;
                }
            }

Comment: Did that help @Shah ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Partitioner.Create(_queue).GetPartitions(4); Partitioner.GetPartions
>   creates 4 partitions but all records are in 1st partition only; 2,3,4
>   partition are empty.

This is not correct, your queue entries are being partitioned correctly. To verify, change your processing logic slightly to log the partition that is doing the work:

```
Task t = Task.WhenAll(
    from partition in partitioner.Select((jobs, i) => new { jobs, i })
    select Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (partition.jobs)
        {
            while (partition.jobs.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(partition.i);
                await CreateJobs(partition.jobs.Current);
            }
        }
    }));
```

You will notice that the `Console.WriteLine` will write values from `0` to `3` - indicating that they are being partitioned correctly.

> Also, I want to remove the item from _queue after processing in
>   consumer method and there is only one way _queue.TryTake method to
>   remove item. I don't know how to remove item along with partitioning?

You can achieve that with a slight rewrite. The main changes are switching to `BlockingCollection` and by adding [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) to give access to `GetConsumingPartitioner`.

Give this a try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestQueue
    {
        BlockingCollection<Job> _queue = new BlockingCollection<Job>();
        private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        public TestQueue()
        {
            WorkProducerThread();
            WorkConsumerThread();
        }

        public void WorkConsumerThread()
        {
            if (!_queue.IsCompleted)
            {
                //At this point, 4 partitions are created but all records are in 1st partition only; 2,3,4 partition are empty
                var partitioner = _queue.GetConsumingPartitioner().GetPartitions(4);

                Task t = Task.WhenAll(
                 from partition in partitioner
                 select Task.Run(async () =>
                 {
                     using (partition)
                     {
                         while (partition.MoveNext())
                             await CreateJobs(partition.Current);
                     }
                 }));


                t.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine(_queue.Count);
            }
        }

        private async Task CreateJobs(Job job)
        {
            //HttpContent bodyContent = null;
            //await _client.PostAsync("job", bodyContent);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }



        public void WorkProducerThread()
        {
            if (_queue.Count == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        Job job = new Job { Id = i, JobName = "j" + i.ToString(), JobCreated = DateTime.Now };
                        _queue.TryAdd(job);
                    }

                    _queue.CompleteAdding();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //_Log.Error("Exception while adding jobs to collection", ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public DateTime JobCreated { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var g = new TestQueue();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks @mjwills it helped a lot..Using ParallelExtensionsExtras, it consumes from queue and remove items also. But in my project this class is part of Windows service where WorkProducerThread is polling every min to get new details and WorkConsumerThread running every min too will consume job from queue and add details to db through Api (CreateJobs method). So I removed _queue.CompleteAdding(); from producer method. But then t.Wait(); in consumer method waits for indefinitely. You can check by commenting the line _queue.CompleteAdding() in above code. Any idea?

Comment: @Shah The nature of `BlockingCollection` is such that it will continue to want to consume until `CompleteAdding` is called. That is a 'feature' rather than a 'bug'.